# Using ASP.NET Core identity authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-identity

I wanted to implement identity authentication on my already function expense tracker website.

I had to make a new dbapplication fixed everything made it to having the website launch and being able to register login but cant seem to be able to logout it just redirect me to login and doesn't logout.

I am not sure if I am using the partial name correctly:

[image]

Comment: Firstly, please do not share your codes via screenshot, we can't copy code from screenshot. You are trying to add asp.net core identity into your application right? If so, could you please let us know how you add the identity into your app? we can't see it in your screenshot. Have you read this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio